# Generation of the designer file for xxxxx failed: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: asp.net, resharper, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.1

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2013, I receive the following warning when I edit the markup of an ASPX or ASCX file, and the designer file does not update with the change. I have ReSharper 8.1 installed. I have tried cleaning the solution, restarting Visual Studio, clearing the Resharper cache, and restarting my computer without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine ran into the same issue, he was able to resolve this but simply suspending resharper and enabling it again.

Answer (score 2):

over here we fixed it by deleting the suo files from the salution,
after that the designer got got rebuild just as normal, on each build